# Is it possible to create a full text index on two or more columns on the same table in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, multiple-columns

Is this possible, or by default is this essentially what I'm doing by creating a full text index on the entire table, specifying in my query which column to query using the 'CONTAINS(column, phrase)' function?

Thanks!

If this question has already been asked (was unable to find a match) please feel free to delete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you implement a fulltext search over multiple columns in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811178/how-do-you-implement-a-fulltext-search-over-multiple-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I already embarrassingly answered my own question [Here, Go to Ctrl + F 'Contains( )'](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/)

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811260/1751090)
with an example how [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315101/SQL-Full-Text-Search-Programming).

Comment: Example is gone
`We're sorry, but the article you are trying to view was deleted at 14 Nov 2013.`