# Index for computed column in a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that is defined like so:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_ListingTestView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 

SELECT 
[ListingID],
[BusinessName],
[Description], 
[ProductDescription],
[Website],
[ListingTypeID],
ISNULL([BusinessName], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([Description], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([ProductDescription], '') + ' ' AS [ComputedText]
FROM dbo.Listings;
```

I use this view when a user searches for a record in the database. The keyword the user provides when searching is compared to the computed column. The columns that are included in the computed column are all NVARCHAR columns. I would like to create an index on this column to help speed up searching.

I was following a tutorial to add an index to the computed column, but I ran into an issue where my computed column was non-deterministic and could not complete the tutorial. If anyone has suggestions on how to accomplish this I would appreciate it. Or if I should go about this a different way.

Answer (score 1):

What length are your columns? [ISNULL()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) is a [deterministic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) function and shouldn't cause any issues.

I'm guessing that's length of your columns that causes it. As you might know, index cannot be longer than 900 symbols. Since you're storing them as [NVARCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), it takes double space as a varchar and needs additional two bytes - this means your index can store up to 448 symbols.

> Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and
>   can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is
>   two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO
>   synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character
>   varying.

So please try to cast your column at specific length, perhaps 400?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_ListingTestView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT [ListingID]
    , [BusinessName]
    , [Description]
    , [ProductDescription]
    , [Website]
    , [ListingTypeID]
    , CAST(ISNULL([BusinessName], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([Description], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([ProductDescription], '') AS NVARCHAR(400)) AS [ComputedText]
FROM dbo.Listings;
```

On top of that, why you'd be creating a view on top of that? Perhaps it would make more sense to alter your table accordingly and only then add index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Listings
ADD [ComputedText] AS CAST(ISNULL([BusinessName], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([Description], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([ProductDescription], '') AS NVARCHAR(400));
```

Now knowing that your NVARCHARS are stored as MAX, perhaps it would be a better idea to start using Full Text Search? This question might be worth looking at then: [How do you implement a fulltext search over multiple columns in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811178/how-do-you-implement-a-fulltext-search-over-multiple-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: The three columns that are included in the computed column actually have a length of BusinessName NVARCHAR(250), Description NVARCHAR(MAX), and ProductDescription NVARCHAR(MAX). I could shorten their lengths, but 400 total is not enough. I could get rid of the view and add the computed column directly to the table, but I'm assuming I'd still run into the issue of being unable to create an index on the computed column due to its length?

Comment: You can cast them as VARCHAR, then length can increase up to 900, but I assume that there must a be a reason you're using a NVARCHAR. By the way, have you considered using [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on top of your table? It might be a better solution

Comment: I was just going to ask if full-text search would be a better solution. If I created a computed column similar to what is in the view on the table, would I be able to add full text search to the computed table column?

Comment: I've added a link in my answer to another question that asks totally the same. *To match across multiple columns, you should concatenate them in a computed column and create an index over that column.* This was said there. You can try that by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I set up a new full text catalog, created the new computed column on the table, and created a full text index on that table. I'll post a follow up answer so anyone else who comes across this question can maybe follow the same steps.